# Chrome Extension affecting links and CSS styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a chrome extension that bolds random letters in a sentence.

```
let containers = document.querySelectorAll('p')
containers.forEach((container) => {
let newtext = container.innerText.split('').map(
m => Math.random() > .49 ? `<strong>`+ m + `</strong>` : m
)
container.innerHTML = newtext.join('')
})
```

The first problem I encountered was that the JavaScript would render `hyperlinks` on the paragraph as plain text.
The second is that when I want to target `li` `span` items, it turns the text into a single paragraph and it also renders those `hyperlinks` as plain text.

My objective is to prevent the code from rendering `hyperlinks` as plain text. But also not to lose the styling of `span` and the `li` items when targeted.

Comment: you're probably losing tags since you read the content using `innerText`

Comment: I tried using ``innerHTML`` but it displays the tags that exist on the page along with its content.

Comment: Well, yes, because using innerHTML you'll randomly break a tag - you need to change your code to only work with text nodes

Comment: I still don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you're removing tags because innerText does not include tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jaromanda X said in the comments, you are breaking the html structure. Your code may get `<p><a>ABC</a></p>` and return `<p><<strong>a</strong>>ABC</a></p>` which is not valid HTML. Try something like this:

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll("*"); // modify the main selector as you want
all.forEach(a => a.childNodes.forEach(b => makeRandomBold(b)));

function makeRandomBold(node) {
  if (node.nodeType !== 3) { // check if it is a text node
    return;
  }
  let text = node.textContent; // backup original content
  node.textContent = ""; // clear content
  text.split('').forEach(s => {
    if (s !== " " && Math.random() > .49) {
      let strong = document.createElement("strong");
      strong.textContent = s;
      node.parentNode.insertBefore(strong, node);
    } else {
      node.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(s), node);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>  Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
  tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis
    elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
</blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
                #header h1 a {
                  display: block;
                  width: 300px;
                  height: 80px;
                }
                </code></pre>
```

Note that this code is not very performant. It may return a lot of continuous strong tags unnecessarily. Instead of individually putting letters in strong tags, I would find random intervals and put them in a single strong tag.